# <ion-footer-bar> displays in iOS Ionic View with thin grey line

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

```
<ion-footer-bar class="pizza-footer">
    <img ng-src="img/pizza_bottom.png" />
</ion-footer-bar>
```

In my stylesheet, I have these styles applied to both the footer bar and the image.

```
ion-footer-bar {
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

Despite this attempt, there is still a thin grey line above the footer bar that I cannot remove. Is there a CSS property I should consider?

NOTE: This grey line only appears when I compile and view the app in Ionic View. Chrome and Safari do not show this grey line.

Comment: You have tried to give a color to that edge? border-color: # FF6E00! important;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ion-footer-bar class="pizza-footer no-line">
    <img ng-src="img/pizza_bottom.png" />
</ion-footer-bar>

.no-line{
  background-color:transparent !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  border:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: That seemed to solve it! Thanks! Do you think you could point out exactly what the property was that caused this to happen? I suspect it was `background-color`.

Answer (score 0):

With ionic 2+ use the attribute `no-border`:

```
<ion-footer no-border>
...
</ion-footer>
```

It works also for `<ion-header>`